# Avoiding the overwriting error google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Can the #REF! "Error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in [cell] be avoided?

For example, I have a table where I have the following below with formula in b1 if I edit the cell in B2 to Favorite Color is green it gives the error.

Goal: a setting and/or formula that will allow the arrayformula to proceed even after editing an existing value generated by the formula without triggering this error.

| Color | `ARRAYFORMULA(if(A1:A<>"",IF(B1:B="","Favorite Color "&A1:A,B1:B),SUBSTITUTE(B1:B,B1:B,B1:B)))` |
| --- | --- |
| green | Favorite Color green |
| orange | Favorite Color orange |

**What I tried that failed:**

1. In the above formula I thought that by using `IF(B1:B="",` then even if I were to edit B2 it should not trigger an error but I realize it still attempting to write
2. I added an iterative calculation setting `File>settings>calculation>Iterative calculation>On, 1, 0.05` so even if I were to change a value in A1:A the existing value would remain in B1:B. I thought this might work.
3. Lastly, I added the condition that if the condition to concatenate isnt met then `SUBSTITUTE(B1:B,B1:B,B1:B)` this doesnt work, because the error is triggerred once an edit takes place but I think if there is some setting to allow the arrayformula to overwrite, effectively, it will simply replace any edited value with itself.

There is no solution, according to [Spencer Faris](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6336618/without-scripts-can-i-override-cells-with-arrayformula-or-see-which-cell-updated-last-dice-roller?hl=en) who says in a Google Response thread "Unfortunately...ARRAYFORMULA() formulas can never override data - they break if you try - and nothing can show you the "last edit" or anything such without a script"

Is this true? or is there another solution such as using a different formula as a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you cannot force the output of an Arrayformula to ignore existing values in the range where it is trying to expand it's result.

Nor can you edit the output of an Arrayformula directly. You can however use that output as the input for a formula in a different column where you perform your transformation/edit.

If you are just trying to append some text before the values in column A you can use this in cell `B1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="","","Favorite Color "&A1:A))
```

Comment: @MMsmithH were you able to try this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes-this error can be avoided by making sure the result of your array formula has room to expand and to avoid intermingling hard-coded values inside a range containing the output of an arrayformula.

Comment: You just gave two different answerS?

Comment: It’s one of those “Yes & No” type situations :)

Comment: No you can’t force the arrayformula to not override existing values but you can avoid the situation that creates those errors